# How to write a function to filter an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm wanting to write a function to filter objects of an array on some condition. I know that when you pass an array to a function, the changes you make to the array inside the function also change the array outside the function (if you are able to make the distinction in the first place anyway). For example,

```
a=[1,2,3]
function addItem(list){
    list.push(4)
}
addItem(a)
// now a = [1,2,3,4]
```

Also, even though the `filter` method only returns a new array and doesn't change the array it was called it, it can be used to change that array by writing `a = a.filter(someFunction)`. I imagine there is some subtlety I'm missing here because when I try to combine these two facts to write a function filtering an array on some condition, the original array isn't changed at all. Here is an example:

```
function isEven(n){
    return (n%2 == 0)
}
function filterOdds(list){
    list = list.filter(isEven)
}
a=[1,2,3,4]
filterOdds(a)
// a is still [1,2,3,4]
```

I suppose I really have two questions:

1. Why doesn't the above code change `a` to `[2,4]`? and
2. How can I write a function to filter lists as I'm trying to do above? Of course, you could get the job done without the function, but what I really want is to filter multiple arrays in a single function. This just seemed like the relevant simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code, you are reassigning the *argument* only. Reassigning a variable will, in almost all cases, have no side-effects; all it'll do is change what further references to that variable *in that scope* will refer to. If there happens to be an outer variable which gets passed as an argument, that outer variable will not get reassigned regardless of what happens inside the function, *unless* the function deliberately reassigns the outer references.

You could implement this by not passing the `list` argument - have `filterOdds` reassign the outer variable:

```js
function isEven(n) {
  return (n % 2 == 0)
}

function filterOdds() {
  list = list.filter(isEven)
}
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
filterOdds()
console.log(list);
```

If you want a more generic solution that'll work for any array passed, since dynamically reassigning an outer variable inside a function isn't possible, your only decent remaining option would be to return the new array and, when calling the function, assign the result:

```js
function isEven(n) {
  return (n % 2 == 0)
}

function filterOdds(list) {
  return list.filter(isEven)
}
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = filterOdds(a)
console.log(a);
```